# What Does :!: Mean?

Tags: php

I saw :!: in a PHP code snippet and am unfamiliar with it. Here's an example in context:

```
:!: $fullname = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
```

From: http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13273

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken, those three characters together have absolutely no meaning in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not valid PHP

```
php > :!: $fullname = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in php shell code on line 1
```

Maybe in the forum they wanted to mark the link.

Answer (score 4):

It is most certainly not a valid PHP.

As far as I am concerned, it is either a typo or a custom 3rd party extension.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this was a smiley inserted by accident. cf. this article: http://www.fastemoticons.net/phpbb.html